# Pandas uptime to datetime with resets to uptime

Tags: python, pandas

I have a main dataframe and several small dataframes (DF_0, DF_1, ...), each one have an uptime column.

DF_main:

```
    (some columns)        uptime
0         .               90094
1         .               90154
2         .               90214
3         .               90274
4         .               90334
.         .               .
.         .               .
.         .               .
1178      .               160774
1179      .               160834
1180      .               160894
.         .               .
.         .               .
.         .               .
1200      .               34
1201      .               94
1202      .               154
1203      .               214
```

DF_0:

```
    (some columns)        uptime
2         .               90094
25        .               90154
45        .               90214
23213     .               160834
23235     .               160894
23258     .               160954
25321     .               154
25359     .               214
```

Think these dataframes like a system log.

1. **uptime** column shows how many time passed since the system started.
2. **DF_main**'s rows represent main events that occur every 60 seconds
3. **DF_0, DF_1, ...** represents events that occurs alongside main events. But they don't occur everytime.

The uptime of DF_main can start with any number and the value in the next row always adds +60 except sometimes the system can reset and next uptime value becomes "(any uptime value) mod 60" (as you can see in the 1200th row in DF_main). And when it resets, it resets for every dataframe.

I need to subtract the first uptime from all the values in the uptime column. But because of the resets in the uptime values, the subtracted values becomes negative.

**Basically I want to:**

1. Change the first uptime of DF_main to 0 and increment next value by +60.
2. Negate all resets, changing the uptime values like no resets happened for every dataframe.

This is quite easy to do if there was no system/uptime resets. But resets confused me.

I know the corresponding timestamp of the first event so if I can achieve this I'll know which event took place in which date and time by summing timestamp with uptime.

What I'm trying to get is like this:

DF_main:

```
    (some columns)        uptime
0         .               0
1         .               60
2         .               120
3         .               180
4         .               240
.         .               .
.         .               .
.         .               .
1178      .               70680
1179      .               70740
1180      .               70800
.         .               .
.         .               .
.         .               .
1200      .               72000
1201      .               72060
1202      .               72120
```

DF_0:

```
(some columns)        uptime
      .               0
      .               60
      .               120
      .               70740
      .               70800
      .               70860
      .               72060
      .               72120
```

I've tried some variations of the code below to at least manage to achieve it with DF_0 but couldn't.

```
first_uptime = int(float(DF_main.iloc[0]['uptime']))
DF_0['uptime'] = DF_0['uptime'].apply(lambda x: x - first_uptime).where(lambda x: x>0, 0)
```

**UPDATE:** I did it using a for loop as much I didn't want to do it with iterating through the dataframe. If you can think of a solution wtihout a for loop, please let me know.

```
for index, row in DT_0.iterrows():
    if (row.uptime - first_uptime < 0):
        first_uptime = row.uptime
    DF_0.at[index, 'uptime'] = row.uptime - first_uptime

first_uptime = int(float(DF_main.iloc[0]['uptime']))

for index, row in DF_main.iterrows():
    if (row.uptime - first_uptime < 0):
        first_uptime = row.uptime
    DF_main.at[index, 'uptime'] = row.uptime - first_uptime
```

Comment: Your index is just a range starting from zero so take that and times it by 60: `df['uptime'] = df.index.values*60`

Comment: @It_is_Chris oh i didn't notice that. thank you. Any ideas for other dataframes?

Comment: It would depend on what the date frame looks like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a decrease in uptime is a sure indication of a reset, here is a general method to calculate cumulative uptime (ignoring resets and even when the logged values are irregular).

```
import pandas as pd

def add_calc_uptime(df, t0=0):
    # Determine when a reset occurred:
    resets = df['uptime'].diff() < 0
    # Make a new variable to denote each run between resets
    df['run_id'] = resets.cumsum()
    # Group results by run
    uptime_by_run_id = df[['run_id', 'uptime']].groupby('run_id')
    cum_uptimes_by_run = {}
    for i, x in uptime_by_run_id:
        # Calculate the uptime values for each run
        cum_uptimes = x['uptime'].diff().cumsum()
        # Replace NaN value in first row
        cum_uptimes.iloc[0] = 0
        # Add final time from previous run to current run
        cum_uptimes = cum_uptimes + t0
        cum_uptimes_by_run[i] = cum_uptimes
        t0 = cum_uptimes.iloc[-1]
    # Add results to dataframe
    df['Uptime Calc'] = pd.concat(cum_uptimes_by_run.values())
    return df


data = [90094, 90154, 90214, 90274, 90334, 34, 94, 154]
DF_main = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['uptime'])
print(add_calc_uptime(DF_main))

data = [90094, 90154, 90214, 160834, 160894, 160954, 154, 214]
index = [2, 25, 45, 23213, 23235, 23258, 25321, 25359]
DF_0 = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=['uptime'])
print(add_calc_uptime(DF_0))
```

Output:

```
   uptime  run_id  Uptime Calc
0   90094       0          0.0
1   90154       0         60.0
2   90214       0        120.0
3   90274       0        180.0
4   90334       0        240.0
5      34       1        240.0
6      94       1        300.0
7     154       1        360.0
       uptime  run_id  Uptime Calc
2       90094       0          0.0
25      90154       0         60.0
45      90214       0        120.0
23213  160834       0      70740.0
23235  160894       0      70800.0
23258  160954       0      70860.0
25321     154       1      70860.0
25359     214       1      70920.0
```

Note: This also assumes that the duration of resets is zero or if not, that a process did not continue to run after the last report before the reset started.

Comment: Thank you! The process continues to run after the last report before the reset started in my case. Is it possible to make this run that way?

Comment: Hard to say since I don't know what `uptime` is actually reporting (uptime since the system restarted or uptime since the system last reported?). If it is the former then you will always loose the uptime between the last report and the beginning of the reset (plus the duration of the reset if you consider that uptime). You will have to figure it out yourself I think.

Comment: B.t.w., you haven't mentioned what happens if the system doesn't reset. What is the maximum possible value of `uptime` and what happens if it is reached?  Does it overflow and go back to zero?  If so, this would also be falsely counted as a reset.

Comment: Finally, what you really need to track uptime is a wall clock.  If you compare uptime with the wall clock you will be able to track downtime or % uptime (not sure if that is what you are actually interested in).

Comment: uptime shows the uptime since the system restarted. And in reality there is no max. uptime, I think it will overflow and go back to zero. I am currently trying to update every uptime value for every run_id by +60 except the rows with the run_id of 0 before they enter the for loop in your code.

Comment: To add 60 to the cum times of the current run just change the line `x = x + t0` to `x = x + t0 + 60`.

Comment: No, I am no trying to add 60 to every cumulative uptime. I am trying to make the calculated uptime to never stay at the same value when a reset occur. For example, In your answer the 5th row of DF_main should be 300, 6th 360 and 7th 360... And for DF_0 calculated uptime of the row with the index of 25321 should be 70920, and the row with the index of 25359 should be 70980.

Comment: Try adding it to this line then: `t0 = x.iloc[-1] + 60`.  Then it won't affect the first run.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was trying to figure out this for an hour by iterating through the dictionary that enters the loop. I can't thank you enough.

Comment: I just simplified the code a bit by combining the dict comprehension with the for loop.